# Get return value from SignalR client

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a SignalR method used to send a request to a specific client and then get a return value. I know this isn't possible, but instead the client needs to send the response as a separate message to the hub.

I send the message to the client from outside the hub:

```
public String GetResponseFromUser(String userId, String request)
{
    // Use requestId to be sure the response is on this request
    var requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
    hubContext.Clients.User(userId).Request(requestId, request);

    // Wait for client to send response to the Hub's Response method
    var response = ...?

    return response;
}
```

Hub class

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Response(String requestId, String response)
    {
        // Somehow I want to get the response to the method above
    }
}
```

How can I wait for the client response and use this response in my method outside the hub?

Answer (score 3):

Once your hub is connected you have to wait and listen for the answer:

```
hubContext.On("Response", (requestId, response) =>
                {
                    // do something 
                }
               );
```

Of course you have to keep that connection alive.

Comment: Great! It was that On method I had missed!

Comment: But sorry, can't find an On method in IHubContext.